# Review queues has a phantom "Low quality posts" flag

Tags: bug, support

I don't know if this is a problem due to me (or my browser) or bug in the SE review system, but when I return to "Computer Graphics" after a day or so, the "review queue" menu nearly always red flags a "low quality" post that needs dealing with... 
[image]

However, when I choose the menu item it immediately says

> This queue has been cleared!

I *suspect* it might refer to a post that I flagged as problematic some number of weeks ago, but I have no way of confirming it. Either way, if anyone knows of a way to stop it reappearing I'd appreciate it.